# FFMPEG video to FLV conversion optimization

Tags: ffmpeg, flv, video-conversion

I have a video site where users can upload videos which will be converted to FLV format and displayed.

Those videos are shown at a size of 420x350.

I'm using FFmpeg to convert then to FLV format through the following command:

```
ffmpeg -i $in $out
```

I find the result to be pretty low quality and whenever I try to change the settings, the output will be a very large file.

I've tried this, for instance:

```
ffmpeg -i $in -sameq -ar 11025 -ab 32 -deinterlace -nr 500 -r 20 -g 500 -s 420x350 -aspect 4:3 -me_range 20 -b 270k -f flv -y $out
```

Does anyone have any tips on optimizing video to FLV conversion using FFmpeg so I could get a medium quality video which is not very large?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try not using -sameq
Also, might want to try to add -vcodec libx264, to produce files compressed with .h264 codec. Which has one of the best quality/size ratios. (although normally used with mp4 container instead of flv)

The audio hz (-ar) are very low, aren't you noticing too low audio quality? At least 22, if not 44100... Also, -b 270k is a bit of a quite low value. I'd set 500, at least.